# Looping functions with timeout

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to have two functions (an animation downwards and animation upwards) executing one after the other in a loop having a timeout of a few seconds between both animations. But I don't know how to say it in JS …

Here what I have so far:

Function 1

```
// Play the Peek animation - downwards
function peekTile() {
    var peekAnimation = WinJS.UI.Animation.createPeekAnimation([tile1, tile2]);

    // Reposition tiles to their desired post-animation position
    tile1.style.top = "-150px";
    tile2.style.top = "-150px";

    peekAnimation.execute();
}
```

Function 2

```
// Play the Peek animation - upwards
function unpeekTile() {
    var peekAnimation = WinJS.UI.Animation.createPeekAnimation([tile1, tile2]);

    // Reposition tiles to their desired post-animation position
    tile1.style.top = "0px";
    tile2.style.top = "0px";

    peekAnimation.execute();
}
```

And here's a sketch how both functions should be executed:

```
var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/updateTile.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {

    peekTile();
    [timeOut]
    unpeekTile();
    [timeOut]
    peekTile();
    [timeOut]
    unpeekTile();
    [timeOut]

    and so on …
    }
});
```

Comment: you can play around with `setTimeout` have posted a working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, so a simple function to do what you want is:

```
function cycleWithDelay() {
    var delay = arguments[arguments.length - 1],
        functions = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, arguments.length - 1),
        pos = 0;
    return setInterval(function () {
        functions[pos++]();
        pos = pos % functions.length;
    }, delay);
}
```

Usage would be like this for you:

```
var si = cycleWithDelay(peekTile, unpeekTile, 300);
```

and to stop it:

```
clearInterval(si);
```

This will just cycle through the functions calling the next one in the list every `delay` msec, repeating back at the beginning when the last one is called.  This will result in your `peekTile`, wait, `unpeekTile`, wait, `peekTile`, etc.

If you prefer to start/stop at will, perhaps a more generic solution would suit you:

```
function Cycler(f) {
    if (!(this instanceof Cycler)) {
        // Force new
        return new Cycler(arguments);
    }
    // Unbox args
    if (f instanceof Function) {
        this.fns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    } else if (f && f.length) {
        this.fns = Array.prototype.slice.call(f);
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid arguments supplied to Cycler constructor.');
    }
    this.pos = 0;
}

Cycler.prototype.start = function (interval) {
    var that = this;
    interval = interval || 1000;
    this.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        that.fns[that.pos++]();
        that.pos %= that.fns.length;
    }, interval);
}

Cycler.prototype.stop = function () {
    if (null !== this.intervalId) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        this.intervalId = null;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var c = Cycler(peekTile, unpeekTile);
c.start();

// Future
c.stop();
```

Comment: for your information I did upvote your answer. The first solution uses `setTimeOut` instead `setTimeout` also it was not functional. You can't just like that blame others. I have clearly mentioned it in my comment. Also you can't influence your way of programming just by down voting others

Comment: Is it possible that the function only starts after 3 seconds with the setTimeout method?

Comment: @just2n great answer, and like the idea of the cycler

Answer (score 0):

You use `setInterval()` to call `unpeekTile()` every 1000 milliseconds and then you call `setTimeOut()` to run `peekTile()` after 1000 milliseconds at the end of the `unpeekTile()` function:

```
function peekTile() {
    var peekAnimation = WinJS.UI.Animation.createPeekAnimation([tile1, tile2]);

    // Reposition tiles to their desired post-animation position
    tile1.style.top = "-150px";
    tile2.style.top = "-150px";

    peekAnimation.execute();
}

function unpeekTile() {
       /* your code here */
     setTimeout(peekTile, 1000);
}

setInterval(unpeekTile, 1000);
```

Comment: How is 1 Sec delay between peekTile and unpeekTile is achieved in your code? ;) Your defn is ok but it is not the same in the code :)

Comment: @Tamil unpeekTile runs every 1000 milliseconds and then its last instruction is `setTimeOut(peekTile,1000);` which waits 1000 milliseconds and then runs the `peekTile()` function.

Comment: Now your edit looks fine. Initially it was not correct. And it is setTimeout not setTimeOut

Answer (score -2):

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFnTW/)

```
var animation  = (function () {
     var peekInterval, unpeekInterval, delay;
     return {
          start: function (ip) {
              delay = ip;
              peekInterval = setTimeout(animation.peekTile, delay);
          },
          peekTile: function () {
             //Your Code goes here
             console.log('peek');
             unpeekInterval = setTimeout(animation.unpeekTile, delay);
          },
          unpeekTile: function () {
            //Your Code goes here
            console.log('unpeek');  
            peekInterval = setTimeout(animation.peekTile, delay);
          },
          stop: function () {
              clearTimeout(peekInterval);
              clearTimeout(unpeekInterval);
          }
    }
         })();
animation.start(1000);
// To stop

setTimeout(animation.stop, 3000);
```

​
I can't use `this` instead of animation.peekTile as `setTimeout` executes in global scope

Comment: @DownVoter Can you plz reason why?